# How to Add X and Y axis in the pre existing graph using D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I have written this code which shows the transition of bars by sing the slider, now I want to show the X and Y axis corresponding to the bars and the slider. Below is my code which is currently missing the x and y axis, can anyone please help me to figure this out. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
div#slider{
    width: 940px;
    margin-left: 5%;

    margin-top: 4%; 
    }
svg {
    margin-left:3%; 
    }
</style>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.1.4" data-semver="2.1.4" src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <link data-require="jqueryui@1.10.0" data-semver="1.10.0" rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" />
    <script data-require="jqueryui@1.10.0" data-semver="1.10.0" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="slider"></div>
<script>
    $(function() {

        $("#slider").slider({
            min: 30,
            max: 950,
            // on slide adjust width of all rects
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                svg.selectAll("rect")
                        .attr("width", function (d) {
                            return Math.min(ui.value * d.rate, d.max);
                        });
            }
        });

        // create svg
        var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", 950)
                .attr("height", 400);


        // add 4 rects
        var data = [
            { row:1, rate:0.4, max:550 },
            { row:2, rate:0.5, max:600 },
            { row:3, rate:0.6, max:700 },
            { row:4, rate:0.7, max:750 },
            { row:5, rate:0.8, max:780 },
            { row:6, rate:0.9, max:800 },
            { row:7, rate:1.0, max:950 },
        ];

        svg.selectAll("rect")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x", 20)
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return d.row * 30;
                })
                .attr("height", 20)
                .attr("width", 20)
                .style("fill","blue")
                .style("margin-top",20);

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to add the axis using d3.scale function. See [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Md83evvn6hNF8b9DWbAU?p=preview) for working example.

```
  //add x and y axis
  var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, 950]);

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([200, 0]);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

  x.domain([0, 950]);

  y.domain([0, 7]);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(20,250)")
    .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(20,30)")
    .call(yAxis);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you please help me customize it by adding the 
1) X-axis data from 0% till 20%
2) Y-axis data ranging from 0-9, 20-29, 40-49, 60-69, 80-80, 100+
3) Adding the data in the slider ranging from 2000, 2010, 2020, 2020, 2030, 2040, 2050 

Thanks in advance.